# Change FilterEditype of janus griex columns to checklistbox

Tags: c#, vb.net, checklistbox, gridex

i Have A Janus Gridex in Windows Form with Several Columns.
I want to Change the FilterEditType of All Columns in This GridEx to Checklistbox. So User Can Filter each Column Based on one or more than one values.

Please Give me the sample Code in C# or VB.net.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add certain events for this one , 
First of all make the GridEx columns `FilterEditType = Custom`
Then add the Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditControls.CheckedComboBox for each column FilterEditType. For eg: add this events

```
    private void grdTest_InitCustomEdit(object sender, Janus.Windows.GridEX.InitCustomEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Key == "ColumnName")
        {
            cboTest.Visible = true;
            e.EditControl = cboTest;
        }
    }
    private void grdTest_EndCustomEdit(object sender, Janus.Windows.GridEX.EndCustomEditEventArgs e)
    {

       //this (dtTest) datatable is actually the datasource assigned for the grid
        dtTest.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        cboTest.Visible = false;
        string Filter = string.Empty;
        if (cboTest.CheckedItems != null)
        {
            foreach (GridEXRow row in cboTest.DropDownList.GetCheckedRows())
            {
                if (Filter != string.Empty)
                    Filter += " OR ColumnName = '";
                else Filter = "( ColumnName = '";
                Filter += row.Cells[2].Value;
                Filter += "'";
            }
            Filter += " )";
        }


        dtTest.DefaultView.RowFilter = Filter;
        grdTest.DataSource = dtTest.DefaultView;
    }
    private void grdTest_ClearFilterButtonClick(object sender, Janus.Windows.GridEX.ColumnActionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Key == "ColumnName")
            cboTest.CheckAll();

        grdTest_EndCustomEdit(null, null);
    }
```

Then for the checked combo you need to design with multiple columns as you need, but one column should be a CheckBox and make it ActAsSelector = True, 
The above example the checked combo has actually 3 columns , first one checkbox , second one is an ID (primary key ) and the last one is the name. I used the name column to filter the datatable.
In the DropDown event of the combo assign the datasource for it from the GirdEx datasource:

```
    private void cboTest_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int C = 1;
        DataRow DR;
        DataTable dtComboDS= new DataTable();
        dtComboDS.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dtComboDS.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        var depts = (from x in dtTest.AsEnumerable() select x.Field<string>("ColumnName")).ToList();// dtTest is actually the datasource assigned for the GridEx
        foreach (var Row in depts.Distinct().ToList())
        {
            DR = dtComboDS.NewRow();
            DR["ID"] = C++;
            DR["Name"] = Row;
            dtComboDS.Rows.Add(DR);
        }
        cboTest.DropDownDataSource = dtComboDS;
    }
    private void cboTest_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cboTest.Visible = false;
        grdTest.UpdateData();
    }
```

On the closeup event hide the checked combo and update the grid to get the result.
Hope this will help !
Good Luck.

Comment: My code is only for one column , for multiple column you have to do it for column by column same procedure